# Amplify Push erroring out when updating CustomResources.json

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-amplify

I'm building a geospatial search on properties using AWS Amplify and ElasticSearch.

I'm currently following this guide: https://gerard-sans.medium.com/finding-the-nearest-locations-around-you-using-aws-amplify-part-2-ce4603605be6

I set up my model as follows

```
type Property @model @searchable @auth(rules: [{allow: public}]) {
  id: ID!
  ...
  Loc: Coord!
}

type Coord {
  lon: Float!
  lat: Float!
}
```

I also added a custom Query:

```
type Query {
 nearbyProperties(
   location: LocationInput!, 
   m: Int, 
   limit: Int, 
   nextToken: String
 ): ModelPropertyConnection
}

input LocationInput {
  lat: Float!
  lon: Float!
}

type ModelPropertyConnection {
 items: [Property]
 total: Int
 nextToken: String
}
```

I added resolvers for request and response:

```
## Query.nearbyProperties.req.vtl
## Objects of type Property will be stored in the /property index

#set( $indexPath = "/property/doc/_search" )
#set( $distance = $util.defaultIfNull($ctx.args.m, 500) )
#set( $limit = $util.defaultIfNull($ctx.args.limit, 10) )
{
  "version": "2017-02-28",
  "operation": "GET",
  "path": "$indexPath.toLowerCase()",
  "params": {
    "body": {
      "from" : 0, 
      "size" : ${limit},
      "query": {
        "bool" : {
          "must" : {
            "match_all" : {}
          },
          "filter" : {
            "geo_distance" : {
              "distance" : "${distance}m",
              "Loc" : $util.toJson($ctx.args.location)
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "sort": [{
        "_geo_distance": {
          "Loc": $util.toJson($ctx.args.location),
          "order": "asc",
          "unit": "m",
          "distance_type": "arc"
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

and response:

```
## Query.nearbyProperties.res.vtl

#set( $items = [] )
#foreach( $entry in $context.result.hits.hits )
  #if( !$foreach.hasNext )
    #set( $nextToken = "$entry.sort.get(0)" )
  #end
  $util.qr($items.add($entry.get("_source")))
#end
$util.toJson({
  "items": $items,
  "total": $ctx.result.hits.total,
  "nextToken": $nextToken
})
```

And now the CustomStacks.json:

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Description": "An auto-generated nested stack.",
  "Metadata": {},
  "Parameters": {
    "AppSyncApiId": {
      "Type": "String",
      "Description": "The id of the AppSync API associated with this project."
    },
    "AppSyncApiName": {
      "Type": "String",
      "Description": "The name of the AppSync API",
      "Default": "AppSyncSimpleTransform"
    },
    "env": {
      "Type": "String",
      "Description": "The environment name. e.g. Dev, Test, or Production",
      "Default": "NONE"
    },
    "S3DeploymentBucket": {
      "Type": "String",
      "Description": "The S3 bucket containing all deployment assets for the project."
    },
    "S3DeploymentRootKey": {
      "Type": "String",
      "Description": "An S3 key relative to the S3DeploymentBucket that points to the root\nof the deployment directory."
    }
  },
  "Resources": {
    "QueryNearbyProperties": {      
     "Type": "AWS::AppSync::Resolver",      
      "Properties": {        
       "ApiId": { "Ref": "AppSyncApiId" },        
       "DataSourceName": "ElasticSearchDomain",        
       "TypeName": "Query",        
       "FieldName": "nearbyProperties",        
       "RequestMappingTemplateS3Location": {          
        "Fn::Sub": [               
  "s3://${S3DeploymentBucket}/${S3DeploymentRootKey}/resolvers/Query.nearbyProperties.req.vtl", {              
         "S3DeploymentBucket": { "Ref": "S3DeploymentBucket" },              
         "S3DeploymentRootKey": { "Ref": "S3DeploymentRootKey" }            
        }]        
       },        
       "ResponseMappingTemplateS3Location": {          
        "Fn::Sub": [            "s3://${S3DeploymentBucket}/${S3DeploymentRootKey}/resolvers/Query.nearbyProperties.res.vtl", {              
         "S3DeploymentBucket": { "Ref": "S3DeploymentBucket" },              
         "S3DeploymentRootKey": { "Ref": "S3DeploymentRootKey" }
        }]        
       }      
      }    
    }
  },
  "Conditions": {
    "HasEnvironmentParameter": {
      "Fn::Not": [
        {
          "Fn::Equals": [
            {
              "Ref": "env"
            },
            "NONE"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "AlwaysFalse": {
      "Fn::Equals": ["true", "false"]
    }
  },
  "Outputs": {
    "EmptyOutput": {
      "Description": "An empty output. You may delete this if you have at least one resource above.",
      "Value": ""
    }
  }
}
```

But when i try to amplify push, it does not work. Something about: Resource is not in the state stackUpdateComplete

Any help?

Comment: `Resource is not in the state stackUpdateComplete` is a generic error. Anyway, did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look in cloudformation at the resource. You're instance is probably stuck in update. Go to : Cloudformation, select your instance (or uncheck view nested first) and go to the events tab. There you will probably find a reason why the instance can't update.

If it's stuck, cancel within the stack actions.